# Definition file for my plugin

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a definition file for my plugin because I will use it with TypeScript and I don't want to have compilation error at any time that I will use it.

I generate the `.d.ts` using gulp-typescript & adding true to relaxation in my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5"
        ]
    },

    "include": [
        "src/ts/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

The compilation works well but I'm dont know how to use it.

**Second point**

After set the declaration file working, I think I will push it to the declaration type repository. I take exemple to some existing typed files, and all have a tsconfig.json and a test file in typescript.

Can you at the same time explain me why they put this two file in addition to the definition file.

**Source :**

To not pollute the topic with the plugin code you can have a look [here](https://github.com/AlexTeixeira/Askmethat-Rating/blob/develop/src/ts/amt-rating.ts) :

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your code with an `outDir` as well. e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The above tsconfig is from TypeStyle that is built with TypeScript and ships with TypeScript definitions : https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle/blob/759ae1fc5a04aef41d22682de7733f4c6067a6dd/tsconfig.json#L8

Comment: It seems that the outdir is not used in my gulp task